# Is there any locality-preserving way to flatten a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, language-agnostic, binary-tree

**Short version:**

[It is possible](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf) to flatten a 2D space into a 1D space such that if 2 points on the 2D space are close together, then their mappings to 1D will also be close together. Similarly, is there any way to map an arbitrary position in a binary tree, to a flat index in an array, such that if two nodes are close together on the tree, then they will be close together on the array?

---

**Long version:**

Let `Tree` be the type of tagged binary trees.

```
               A 
            /     \
           B       C
          / \     / \
         D   E   F   G
        / \ / \ / \ / \
        H I J K L M N O
```

A position on in a `Tree` can be given by a bit string where `0` means `go left`, `1` means `go right` and the empty string is root (`A`). For example, `011` points to `K` on the tree above. Moreover, let the `distance` between two nodes be the number of steps it takes to go from one to another.

What is a map `F :: BitString -> Nat` from node locations (bitstrings) to natural numbers such that if `distance(A, B)` is small, then `|F(A) - F(B)|` is small?

Comment: Yes. How about a heap: root is node `i`, with children `2i + 1` and `2i + 2`? If you want to minimise the distance, though, we'd have to think harder. :-)

Comment: Well in general you will need to make a tradeoff of some sorts. If you're interested in good cache locality of subtrees, then you should check out the "van Emde Boas layout", e.g. described here: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS395T/2013fa/lectures/MemoryOptimizations_2013.pdf

In your example that would be ABCDHIEJKFLMGNO. It has the property that no matter what your cache size is, if you traverse the tree depth-first then at some point the whole subtree hanging from the current node is completely in the cache

Comment: This is terrible for locality purposes. Using that formula, `L`'s index is 11 while `K`'s index is `12` - 1 apart, even though they are the furthest nodes on the graph. Yet, `F`'s index is 5, even though it is the closest node of `L`.

Comment: Yes @NiklasB., I want cache efficiency, in particular for [this graph rewriting system](http://www.xmloperator.net/lambda2/resources/combinators_rules.png). I'd like to implement it on the GPU, so I need to somehow make sure that two nodes close together logically are close together in memory, so I can partition the work in spatial clusters. I'll have this as a separate question, though. If you have any insight let me know. I'll check that link, thanks.

Comment: In terms of cache efficiency, have you looked at [Cache Oblivious Search Trees via Binary Trees of Small Height](http://www.cs.au.dk/~gerth/papers/soda02.pdf)?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis FWIW, that's the dynamic case of v.E.B. They also try to make the index mapping implicit to be more efficient

Comment: Woops, I think I made a little confusion, nevermind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [TilmannZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35083377/3233921) (which uses infix ordering) is about as good as it's going to get.  Consider that every node in your binary tree, apart from the root, has three neighbors, and in a 1D memory layout, only two of them can actually be a distance of 1 away.  Also, not many other useful orderings come to mind.

I've written a small [Perl script](https://ideone.com/6UX9KR) which compares the default ordering to a depth-first prefix ordering and an infix ordering.  You can throw the output at [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) to get the following plot (**edit**: included van-Emde-Boas layout):
[image: plot showing the memory locality of different node orderings]

You can see that the original ordering has relatively bad locality for small tree distances, and both the prefix and infix orderings are better. The infix ordering produces the best behaviour of the three, though (e.g., nodes at a tree distance of 3 are on average 6 memory indices apart). It is also an almost linear curve, which should be a good indicator that you cannot do much better.  The V.E.B. layout mentioned in the comments does not as well at least for smaller node distances, according to your distance criterion.

For sake of completeness, here's the (somewhat quick and dirty) script I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Compares node distances in memory for different layouts of the following
# binary tree:
#                      A
#                  /       \
#              B               C
#            /   \           /   \
#          D       E       F       G
#         / \     / \     / \     / \
#        H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
#       / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \
#       P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4

# Calculates the real node distance.
sub dist($$)
{
  my ($i, $j) = @_;
  return 0 if ($i == $j);
  ($j,$i) = ($i,$j) if ($i > $j);
  # $i<$j. Go one up from the larger node.
  return 1 + dist($i, ($j-1)>>1);
}

# Determines the average memory distance for nodes as a function of tree distance.
sub get_dists($$)
{
  my $tree = shift;     # Original tree ordering
  my $locality = shift; # Locality-based ordering

  my %dists = ();
  my %counts = ();

  for (my $i=0; $i<length($tree); $i++)
  {
    for (my $j=$i; $j<length($tree); $j++)
    {
      # Find location of $i and $j in the locality-based ordering.
      my $ni = substr($tree, $i, 1);
      my $nj = substr($tree, $j, 1);
      my $it = index($locality, $ni);
      my $jt = index($locality, $nj);
      my $d = (($i <= $j) ? ($j-$i) : ($i-$j));
      my $dt = (($it <= $jt) ? ($jt-$it) : ($it-$jt));
      my $treedist = dist($i, $j);
      $dists{$treedist} += $dt;
      $counts{$treedist}++;
    }
  }
  foreach my $k (sort keys %counts)
  {
    $dists{$k} /= $counts{$k};
  }
  return %dists;
}

my $tree = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234";    # original (breadth-first prefix) ordering
my $prefix = "ABDHPQIRSEJTUKVWCFLXYMZ0GN12O34";  # depth-first prefix ordering
my $infix = "PHQDRISBTJUEVKWAXLYFZM0C1N2G3O4";   # infix ordering
my $veb = "ABCDHPQIRSEJTUKVMFLXYMZ0GN12O34";     # V.E.B. layout (hope I got it right)

my %original_dists = get_dists($tree, $tree);
my %prefix_dists = get_dists($tree, $prefix);
my %infix_dists = get_dists($tree, $infix);
my %veb_dists = get_dists($tree, $veb);

print "set key top left;\n";
print "set title 'Locality ratios';\n";
print "set xlabel 'tree distance';\n";
print "set ylabel 'avg. memory distance';\n";

print "plot '-' w lp title 'original', '-' w lp title 'prefix ordering', '-' w lp title 'infix ordering', '-' w lp title 'van-Emde-Boas layout';\n";

foreach my $k (sort keys %original_dists)
{
  print "$k $original_dists{$k}\n";
}
print "e\n";
foreach my $k (sort keys %prefix_dists)
{
  print "$k $prefix_dists{$k}\n";
}
print "e\n";
foreach my $k (sort keys %infix_dists)
{
  print "$k $infix_dists{$k}\n";
}
print "e\n";
foreach my $k (sort keys %veb_dists)
{
  print "$k $veb_dists{$k}\n";
}
print "e\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the insightful research.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to look at space-filling curves. The simplest one is the [z-curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) (also called Morton order), which can be created by interleaving the bits of the x and y coordinate into something called a z-value. If the resulting z-values for two 2D point have a small distance then the original points are also no far away. The reverse is unfortunately not always true, there are some exceptions where neighbouring 2D points get very different z-values.

A better proximity (likelihood of small `distance(A,B)` -> small `|F(A)-F(B)|` can be achieved with [Hilbert curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve), however they are more difficult to calculate.

For both algorithms there a bit-level hacks available to calculate them very fast, see for example the excellent [Hacker's delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org) book (I'm not affiliated, I just like it a lot).

Comment: FWIW, have a look at my tree implementation (https://github.com/tzaeschke/critbit). It is a bit-wise 0-left/1-right tree with tools for interleaving the bits and performing reasonably efficient 2D rectangular queries on the dataset. However, for such queries there a better options, let me know if this is a priority.

Comment: I'm aware of the Z-Curve, but it is for 2D/3D spaces. It doesn't the solve the problem of storing a huge binary try - how would you lay out your binary tree on the space?

Comment: Ah, it looks like I misunderstood the question. I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to flatten a tree with a known height, then the basic approach could be to interleave the nodes. For the example above this would result in an array with `[H,D,I,B,J,E,K,A,...]` and so forth. proximity is not ideal, but probably as close as you can get. To calculate the position you could do as follows.
Lets say `h` is the height of your node, counting from 0 (bottom: H,I,J,K,.. ) to 3 (top: A). If you encode the nodes as described, i.e. `H=000,B=00,I=001,` then the array position would be `pos(node)=value(node)*2 + (2^h)-1`. For example `pos(H=000)=0`, `pos(B=00)=1`, `pos(I=001)=2`, ... .

One problem is obviously that increasing the height of the tree is best done by inserting nodes above 'A', otherwise you would have to re-map all nodes.

**Edit**
The locality requirement of this algorithm is of course not very good for top-level nodes (A/B) but reasonably good for most lower level nodes (except K/L). It really depends what type of locality is important. If locality of high-level nodes is important, than the ABCDEFG ordering in the comments of the questions is probably best.

I don't think there is a perfect solution that works in all cases.

Comment: Well this is better than the other answer but still quite unsatisfactory, but maybe it is just something impossible to do.